# How to display the value which is found in vlookup

Tags: excel

I got an Excel like this:

```
---------
| 1 | a |
---------
| 2 | b |
---------
| 3 | c |
---------
| 4 | d |
---------
| 5 | e | 
---------
```

and a table like this:

```
---------
| 4 | d |
---------
| 3 | k |
---------
| 2 | b |
---------
| 1 | a |
---------
```

Now I want to check: If the data of the first column is the same in both tables, then if the second column is not the same, it has to display the value of the other table. So like this:

```
---------------------
| 1 | a | correct   |
---------------------
| 2 | b | correct   |
---------------------
| 3 | c | k         |
---------------------
| 4 | d | correct   |
---------------------
| 5 | e | not found |
---------------------
```

This is what I already have:
     `=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F2;A:B;2;FALSE)=G2;"Correct";"Wrong");"Not Found")`
The "wrong" needs to change in some sort of formula.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have it in your formula. the below part gives you the value in the 2nd table corresponding to the number. this you are checking if it matches with the value in the first table. if it does not match, print this else print correct

```
VLOOKUP(F3,$F$8:$G$11,2,FALSE)
```

The formula should be

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F3,$F$8:$G$11,2,FALSE)=G3,"Correct",VLOOKUP(F3,$F$8:$G$11,2,FALSE)),"Not Found")
```

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1poCm-x8IVK21VYKVI6PkE1QJMd87A91jI19h4FrS4RM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"Wrong"` with `VLOOKUP(F2;A:B;2;FALSE)`